# Import jQuery & other libraries in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, types, mean-stack

after days of research and struggeling I have to ask here to fine someone to clearify the process of **importing a library in Typescript**.

I was used to just add the  tag and everything works fine.
Now that I´m trying to build a **MEAN-Stack** application I don´t figure out how that all works with the definition files and such...

**WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:**

```
npm install jquery //terminal root: /project/angular-src
npm install @types/jquery //same directory here
```

then I importet jQuery in the one of my .ts files

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

I tried out several variations of this ( installing jQuery and @types/jQuery in the project folder instead of the angular-src folder) but none of it worked for me. I thought it would be that simple but maybe I´m missing something out here. I always get some kind of errors like "Generic type 'xyz' requires x arguments" ( like 200 rows of these )

Hope you can help me explain why this doesnt work and how I can make it work

PS: I found similar questions here before but I didnt really find them helpful as I tried them out with no success

Comment: The A in MEAN means Angular. Why on Earth would you need jQuery along with Angular? Don't use jQuery, problem solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JQuery and Angular are two separate things either use Angular or JQuery.

Comment: ...or even better, don't import jQuery and stick with Angular.

Comment: @JeremyThille quite a sensible approach.But if still the jquery is to be used

Comment: You don't need to. If you use Angular, you don't need jQuery. If you _absolutely_ need jQuery, then build a jQuery app, not an Angular app. Don't mix up these two.

Comment: Okay thanks guys...seems like that was the wrong approach... I´ll read myself a bit better into angular 2 then... Can I really get same results as easy with angular than with jquery ( .hide /.show / .datepicker and such functionality with animations)

Comment: @JohannesBeiser
Please upvote the answer so it could help others in the community.And yes you can get angular 2 like JQuery.I would advise you to read some docs before starting a project.Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

You can, in fact, use jQuery with TypeScript. You will need to download the jQuery definition file located [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/jquery).

With that downloaded, copy the definition file (under the v2 folder, 'index.d.ts' file) to your solution/project.

Once added to your project, you can reference the jQuery definition file by adding this to the top of your .ts file:

`///<reference path="../{your-location}/jquery.d.ts"/>`

Which should enable jQuery in your TypeScript app.